# Getting error in setting Transdirect Shipping sender APi code

Tags: php

I am trying to implement transdirect.com shipping set sender API to my website but i am getting error i don't know what is the main cause of it.

here is the snippet::

```
$params = array(
    'session' => $session,
    'postcode' => '2164',
    'name' => 'abc',
    'company'=>'abc',
    'email' => $email ,
    'phone' => '4561237',
    'streetName' => 'abcStreet',
    'streetNumber' => '28',
    'streetType' => 'St',
    'suburb' => 'JHONFEILD',
    'state' => 'NSW',
    'pickupDate' => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
    'pickupTime' => '1-4pm',
    'hydraulicGate' =>'false'
);
$query = http_build_query($params);
$query = 'http://transdirect.com.au/api/v2/booking/sender?'.$query;
$result = json_decode( curl_sender( $query, $session, $email, $arg = 'sender') );
```

// curl_sender method::

```
function curl_sender( $url, $session, $email, $arg ) {
    if ( $arg == 'sender' ) {
         $datastring = "postcode=2164&name=Tara Trampolines&company=abc&email=".$email."&phone=0280049375&streetName=Unit 4/28 Victoria St&streetNumber=28&streetType=St&suburb=SMITHFIELD&state=NSW&pickupDate". date( 'Y-m-d' )."&pickupTime=1-4pm&hydraulicGate=false";
   }
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastring);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $data1 = curl_exec( $ch );
   curl_close( $ch );
   return $data1;
}
```

I am getting:

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [message] => Must be authenticated-please create a session first. 
    [code] => 403
)
```

Here is the link from we have implemented the api::
   http://transdirect.com.au/api/v2/documentation

please specify how we can authenticate each method.
   Any help will be appreciable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The page you linked yourself has a paragraph “Create Session” …

Answer (score 0):

You've to create a valid session before you requesting the API.

Create the session:

```
$credentials = array(
    'email' => 'test@example.com',
    'password' => 'secret'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $credentials);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Take a look at the session part: http://transdirect.com.au/api/v2/documentation

You can't mix the session creation process and the real API request.

1. Create session
2. Create API request with this session from step 1.

I'm not sure but I think you don't have to use the valid session as any parameter.
The documentation says only create a valid session, there is no parameter specified to append the session, so creation is maybe enough.

This is maybe very important for you:

> Confirm booking with any special instructions etc. Once the booking is
>   confirmed your session is cleared and you will need to
>   re-authenticate.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply,we have created the session and i am getting stdClass Object ( [session] => 0v1hci76lvvhvkcaffbr6j1im3 [code] => 200 ) in response. Please let us know how to use the session created in 1step for shippment booking

Comment: I think you've to open a support ticket. The documentation is really odd. There is no hint how to use the session, only how do you create one. I think you tried to append the session as GET and as POST, these are your options. Maybe ignore the session as parameter. Create a session and then continue straight forward as the documentation describes.

Comment: I really appreciate for you immediate reply, I have implemented the api as the document narrates. But didn't achieved success it is giving me same error 
stdClass Object ( 
    [message] => Must be authenticated-please create a session first. 
    [code] => 403
)
 after the success response  of create session I.e :: stdClass Object ( [session] => 0v1hci76lvvhvkcaffbr6j1im3 [code] => 200 ) 
So it mean we need to set session in further methods of transdirect api :(

Comment: I think you did nothing wrong. In my opinion, stop wasting your time and contact the support. There is no part in the documentation how to work with the created session and the example is really pointless without session handling. All other solutions are try & error and maybe very frustrating.